# Can I get React to notice when a property on an object in an array passed to props changes its value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to avoid extra work by adding a property to an object in an array of objects `onMouseEnter` when I mouse over the `ApartmentCard` displaying info about a given apartment.

There is also a map beside the list of `ApartmentCards`. The map has a marker for each apartment. My goal is to make React retrigger `useEffect` so that all the old markers are removed, and new ones are placed, including one that will be highlighted to indicate it is the associated marker.

(As an aside, it's possible selecting the appropriate marker and updating its color would be more efficient, but that's for later)

So currently in my `ApartmentCard.tsx` I have:

```
interface ApartmentCardProps {
    apartment: IHousing;
    addr: string;
    gyms: IAssociation[];

    apUrl: string;
}

const ApartmentCard: React.FC<ApartmentCardProps> = ({ apartment, addr, gyms, apUrl }) => {
    return (
        <div
            onMouseEnter={() => {
                console.log("mouse enter", "23rm");
                apartment.isHighlighted = true;
            }}
            onMouseLeave={() => {
                apartment.isHighlighted = false;
            }}
        >Apartment address, other data</div>
 };

export default ApartmentCard;
```

On the `IHousing` interface there is some predictable stuff that I left out, but also:

```
export interface IHousing {
    type: "apartment" | "house";
    // snip
    isHighlighted?: boolean;
}
```

`ApartmentCard` is a child component of `MapPage`. `Map` is also a child of `MapPage`. Both receive the same data about apartments, so when `isHighlighted` is updated in `ApartmentCard`, the objects used to populate `Map` immediately update their property and values with `isHighlighted = true` or `false`.

Here's some code from `Map.tsx`:

```
interface MapboxProps {
    center: [number, number];
    qualifiedFromCurrentPage: IHousing[];
    // zoom: number;
}

const Map: React.FC<MapboxProps> = ({ center, qualifiedFromCurrentPage }) => {
    const [markers, setMarkers] = useState<mapboxgl.Marker[]>([]);
    const { isOpen, toggleIsOpen } = useContext(SidebarStateContext) as ISidebarContext;

    // initialization of map has been removed to save space in the post

    // plot qualified gyms and apartments
    useEffect(() => {
        if (map === null) return;

        let allMarkers: mapboxgl.Marker[] = [];
        if (qualifiedFromCurrentPage.length !== 0 && map.current) {
            const { apartmentMarkers, gymMarkers } = unpackMarkers(qualifiedFromCurrentPage);
            allMarkers = [apartmentMarkers, gymMarkers].flat();

            addNewMarkers(allMarkers, markers, setMarkers, map.current);
        }
        return () => {
            // remove all old markers
            for (const marker of allMarkers) {
                marker.remove();
            }
        };
    }, [map, qualifiedFromCurrentPage]);

    function unpackMarkers(pageMarkers: IHousing[]): { apartmentMarkers: mapboxgl.Marker[]; gymMarkers: mapboxgl.Marker[] } {
        // snip
    }

    function addNewMarkers(newMarkers: mapboxgl.Marker[], oldMarkers: mapboxgl.Marker[], markerUpdater: Function, map: mapboxgl.Map) {
           // snip
    }

    return (
        <div id="mapContainerOuter" className={`${decideWidth(isOpen, isOnMobile)} w-full mapHeight mr-2`}>
            <div id="mapContainer" ref={mapContainer}></div>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    console.log(qualifiedFromCurrentPage, "142");
                }}
            >
                Test
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Map;
```

What I was really hoping for was that the `useEffect` hook with `qualifiedFromCurrentPage` in its dependency array would run again when the property changes on one of its objects. But it ignores it.

One solution that *for sure would work* is if (1) I assigned a number to each apartment in the list for a given page then (2) let the `ApartmentCard` set the active value, probably stored in the parent `MapPage`, which would then (3) be passed down into the `Map` component and used to highlight the associated marker.

It could and would work. But, given that I'm supposed to be a professional React user, and I'm not getting an expected behavior, I would really like to know what's going on. Shouldn't adding a property to an object in an array cause React to re-run that useEffect hook? That's what I expected.

Thanks all

edit: I am feeding in [a shallow copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy) to both `apartmentCard` and `Map` from this function in `MapPage`, but I thought it would be fine since the values of a shallow copy point to the same objects as the input array.

```
    function getCurrentPageResults(qualified: IHousing[], page: number): IHousing[] {
        if (qualified.length < 10) {
            return qualified;
        }
        const startOfPage = page * 10 - 10;
        const endOfPage = page * 10 - 1;
        return qualified.slice(startOfPage, endOfPage);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're a former Vue user? React doesnt watch the change of object or variables, in fact, you have to notify React that some value changes by `setState` or state hook, and then React will handle the virtual dom result diff and rerender the real dom only in need.

React's one-way data flow (also called one-way binding, opposite to two-way binding) keeps everything modular and fast. You can check [thinking-in-react](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) for more detail.

Comment: I see. So the path I outline at the bottom of my post, where I give every apartment its own id, is the correct path. I was presuming that updating the contents of the state would cause a re-render.

Comment: Yes, thats the correct way, also known as a state lift. You should avoid mutating values that you are using as props or state, since React use simple shallow comparison between the old and new values.